# Mechanical Turk - Fetch results for a batch via API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

We've created batches of HITs using the Mechanical Turk web interface. Now all we want to do is download the results for a batch using the API, the same way you can download the results for a batch in the web interface using "Download CSV".

The documentation from Amazon says that downloading the results from the API is possible and I would be surprised if it isn't. But after a lot of programming hours and testing I have not been able to get the results of a batch.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_OperationsArticle.html

Our problem is not to get the HIT data, that stuff is easy with `GetHIT`. Our problem isn't either to get the assignment data, that's easily done with `GetAssignmentsForHIT`. Our problem is to figure out the HIT IDs of a batch so that we only fetch the results of that batch.

We thought we would be able to do this with `GetHITsForQualificationType` but since we use the same HIT type ID for all batches this isn't possible. The only other operation I can see is SearchHITs, but this operation only lets you "sort" values and not "filter" by e.g batch ID.

If Amazon is a SOA company and they follow the "eat your own dog food" concept, then I wonder how they generate the results in "Download CSV" using their API?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE #1**

I believe you could use `SearchHITs` to pull out *all* HITs. Then grab the details for each HIT using `GetHIT`. Then filter all the HITs by "RequesterAnnotation" which actually contains the batch ID, e.g "BatchId:1234567;". This might be the only solution. Sounds a bit far fetched though.

Comment: What is "Batch ID"? I've never seen this term in the API documentation.

Comment: There's probably no such thing, but when you create HITs using the web interface using a CSV file Amazon refers to those with the wording "batches". A batch consists of multiple HITs. The batch ID is nothing they promote, but you can see it in the URL when browsing the batches.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is exactly as you describe in your Update #1:
(1) Use `SearchHITs` to get all of your HITs.
(2) Get details with `GetHIT` (You can actually skip this step because the "Requester Annotation" field comes with `SearchHITs` if you include the `HITDetail` response group).
(3) Filter the results by the annotation field to get the HITs you want.
(4) Use `GetAssignmentsForHIT` to retrieve assignments.

The "batch id" is something that appears to only be accessible to Amazon for use on the Requester User Interface. (see some discussion [on the MTurk Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=422027&#422027))

And, of course, the API is going to give you results in XML, which you'll need to parse to turn them into a CSV.